# three.js how to add Pointcloud as textfile

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, point-clouds

i try to add Point cloud file "txt" to html page using three.js.
i get alwas Black screen

file content:

```
0.0802   212.8271   -119.7713   0619
0.0690   212.8270   -119.6854   0629
0.0578   212.8269   -119.5996   0633
0.0839   212.8269   -119.5214   0666
0.1473   212.8269   -119.4507   0646
0.1361   212.8268   -119.3649   0637
0.1324   212.8267   -119.2806   0624
0.1287   212.8267   -119.1962   0604
0.0727   212.8266   -119.1014   0629
0.0765   212.8265   -119.0186   0640
0.0727   212.8265   -118.9343   0671
0.0467   212.8264   -118.8455   0675
0.0802   212.8264   -118.7687   0623
0.0989   212.8263   -118.6888   0612
0.0877   212.8263   -118.6030   0565
0.0318   212.8262   -118.5084   0626
.....
```

```
    <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
    <script>
    
      // Initialisiere Three.js
          const scene = new THREE.Scene();
          const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
            75,
            window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
            0.1,
            1000
          );
          
        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        //scene.add(camera);
        // Lade Punktwolken-Daten aus der TXT-Datei
        const loader = new THREE.FileLoader();
        loader.load(
            'pointcloud.txt',
            (data) => {
                // Verarbeite die geladenen Daten
                const points = data.split('\n').map(line => {
                    const coordinates = line.split('   ').map(parseFloat);
                    if (coordinates.some(isNaN)) {
                        console.log('Skipping invalid data:', coordinates);
                        return null;
                    }
                    return new THREE.Vector3(coordinates[0], coordinates[1], coordinates[2]);
                }).filter(point => point !== null);

                const geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points);
                 //create a blue LineBasicMaterial
                const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff } );
                const pointCloud = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
                scene.add(pointCloud);


                // Beleuchtung hinzufügen (optional)
                const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1);
                pointLight.position.set(0, 0, 10);
                scene.add(pointLight);
                // Füge die Punktwolke zur Szene hinzu
                
                 camera.position.z = 5;
                 camera.position.y = 1;
                 camera.rotation.x = (3.141 / 180) * -10; // 20 deg
                // Setze die Kamera-Position
                //camera.position.z = 50;

                // Rendere die Szene
                const animate = function () {
                    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                    renderer.render(scene, camera);
                };

                animate();
            },
            undefined,
            (error) => {
                console.error('Fehler beim Laden der Datei', error);
            }
        );
        
    </script>
```